# Why is String final?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is String final in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068804/why-is-string-final-in-java)

I'm just wondering why `java.lang.String` is made `final`? Is it to prevent from being inherited? Why?

Comment: Same as [Why is String final in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068804/why-is-string-final-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed.  This allows code in security managers and classloaders to work with the String type without having to worry that it's actually dealing with a malicious subclass that's specifically designed to trick it into allowing evil code through.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be extending the string class. Just write your own methods in some other class that manipulate strings.

The reason is that the string class is a stable one which should not be tampered with as you may re-define some methods which would have unknown side effects on some other transactions.

Comment: I think question was about 'why', not what...

Comment: @StaxMan your right... I've added a bit more than just a no.

Comment: But if that is the reason, they can declare only the methods `final` to prevent from being overridden, not the whole class. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from security aspects that were already mentioned, I suspect performance was another important reason. For older JVMs especially final classes (where all methods are final by definition) made it much easier to inline code on-the-fly. And since String is one of most heavily used objects, which affects overall performance of many applications, this was seen as an area where improvements would have big overall effect.