# Override java string methods

Tags: java, string, overriding

Can we override all the methods of String class in our class by extending String class?

Comment: What is your problem that you want to override the String method?

Comment: Did it ever occur to you to ***try it?***

Answer (score 12):

[`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is [`final`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html) class you can't `extend` it

You also might be interested to know why it is [`final`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html) and why you can't extend it, The core reason is its immutability

---

**See**

- [why-is-string-final-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068804/why-is-string-final-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

No. [`String` is `final`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and therefore cannot be extended.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that as String class is Final.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand why you want to override String methods.

You can not do it as `String class is final`.

but you can add extra functionality to String methods by using composition like below

```
public class Example{
private String str;
public Example(String str){
    this.str=str;
}
public int length(){
    return str.length()+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't override `final` classes, of which `String` is one.

You can, though, create your own class with String helper functions.

e.g.,

```
public class StringHelper
{
    public static String DoSomethingHelpfulToAString(String stringToDoStuffTo)
    {
        return "This string is now helpful";
    }
}
```

then, just use the helper function on your string:

```
string stringToModify = "blah";
string modifiedString = StringHelper.DoSomethingHelpfulToAString(stringToModify);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` is a `final` class and thus you can't have another class `extend` it.