# Java: How can I see how many strings are stored in pool of strings?

Tags: java, jvm

As you all know, JVM holds a special segment in memory destinated for strings. Do you know how I can see all strings placed in pool of strings? If it's not possible to see the strings themselves, is it possible to see the number of strings stored?

Comment: Maybe the answer from this question will help you ;)[Printing String in intern pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094111/how-to-print-the-whole-string-pool)

Comment: @SidsonAidson Not really, as it doesn't work. It doesn't count literals pooled by the compiler, for a start.

Comment: To see just the number and the size of pooled strings use `jmap -heap <pid>`