# Create immutable object, instantiated without new

Tags: java, string, object, instance

Can I create a class that instantiates with just the `=` operator, like the `String` class does? Or is that a feature specific to `String` class in Java?

Comment: No, you can't. It's something that, as you said, `lies inside Java`.

Comment: And Strings are *not* instantiated with `=`. String constants are defined with `"..."` and it only gets more complicated from there. So, no, you cannot. Use `new`. If you do not like `new`, you can hide it behind a static factory method or something like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068570/how-to-create-a-string-class-replica

Comment: I meant If I Can I tell Java what to do if there is "=" next to my class or "+=". I gave String class just an example of this. Not internals of String class. I get answer by replies  with user-defined Operator Overloading. Thanks all.

Comment: @matthew - Java doesn't actually do anything special for "=" with strings (it does for "+=", but only because it has special behaviour for "+").

Comment: If you are interested in this I highly recommend playing around with Groovy.  You can run 100% java classes through groovy (it's nearly a perfect superset) but it also allows a lot of new syntax such as operator overloading.  I prefer Java for production code, but Groovy is a lot of fun to mess around with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because Java does not support **user-defined Operator Overloading** a new instance can not be created with `=` Operator.

Check out [Why doesn't Java offer operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/why-doesnt-java-offer-operator-overloading) for more information

Answer (score 16):

**No, you can't** create a class that's instantiated just with `=` operator because **you can't overload an operator in Java like you can in C++ or C#** (see [Operator overloading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java)).

`String`s are instantiated when you use `"something"` only if they do not already exist in memory, so you get a reference to the same exact `String` object each time you write `"something"`.

For example, if you do:

```java
String a = "something";
String b = "something";
```

Then

```java
a == b; // will be true.
```

You can take a look at these questions to learn more about how `String` objects work:

- [Strings are objects in Java, so why don't we use 'new' to create them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them)
- [What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext)
- [What is Java String interning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning)

Answer (score 7):

Code `String s = "Hello World!"` does not create a new `String`. It assigns a reference of a `String` existing in String Pool to `s`. If the `String` does not exist in String Pool, then a new `String` object is created in String Pool, but not with the operator `=` all alone.

This creates new `String` objecs:

```
String s1 = new String("Hello World!"); // new Object
String s2 = new String("Hello World!"); // new Object

System.out.println(s1 == s2); // false
```

This may or may not create a new `String` object in String Pool:

```
String s1 = "Hello World!";
String s2 = "Hello World!";

System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true
```

You could get fairly close to the behaviour mentioned above with using `getInstance()` pattern, consider this:

```
public class Singleton {
  private Singleton(){}

  private static class SingletonHelper{
    private static final instance INSTANCE = new Singleton();
  }

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Then you could use:

```
Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
```

Comment: The first code snippet does not necessarily create a new `String` in the string pool (the strings created by `new String(...)` are not contained in the pool).

Comment: @Nevay You are of course right, my fault, corrected my answer.